# Is it safe to use custom http headers which don't start with 'X-'

Tags: http, http-headers

According to [RFC 6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648) which has deprecated the 'X-' convention, there is no reason to prefix custom headers like API key with 'X-' for designing web API now.

In spite of RFC standard, I wonder that it is really safe to conform the new convention, without 'X-'. Someone says that some browsers or even some ISPs which follow the old convention may block such headers which follow the new convention by reason of non-standard but I couldn't confirm that yet.

The solution would be simple, supporting both conventions or old convention only. Though, regardless of the solution, I'd like to know if it is safe or not to conform the new convention or is a question with no answer.